# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file---- for my submit page

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

I am getting error in this line

`<?php echo $__env->make('layout.app', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>`

The error while submitting the page is as below:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file (View: C:\laragon\www\todolist\resources\views\todo\home.blade.php)"

**Please help**

Also My home.blade.php has this

```
@extends('layout.app')
@section('body')
    <br>
    <a href="todo/create" class="btn btn-info">Add New</a>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        <center><h1>Todo Lists</h1></center>
        <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach($todos as $todo)
            <li class="list-group-item">
            {{$todo->body}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is your @endforeach

Answer (score 3):

You need to add [`@endsection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#extending-a-layout) to the end of the blade file:

```
@extends('layout.app')
@section('body')
    <br>
    <a href="todo/create" class="btn btn-info">Add New</a>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        <center><h1>Todo Lists</h1></center>
        <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach($todos as $todo)
            <li class="list-group-item">
            {{$todo->body}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be an "@endforeach" after the closing li tag:

```
@extends('layout.app')
@section('body')
    <br>
    <a href="todo/create" class="btn btn-info">Add New</a>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        <center><h1>Todo Lists</h1></center>
        <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach($todos as $todo)
            <li class="list-group-item">
            {{$todo->body}}
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you use `<?php   your code ?>` or `<? your code ?>` instead of `@php your code @endphp` you can get the same error

in general, this will happen if you forget to close @enif @endforeach @endsection etc ...